# Issues of using input/output context to control intent flow

Tags: dialogflow-es

When we use input and output context to control the flow of intents A, B, C, and D as flowing:

> intent B -> intent A;
> intent C -> intent A;
> intent D -> intent A;

Should I add contexts of B\C\D to intent A?
Or should I create different versions of intent A?

The problem is, if I use output contexts of B, C and D as the input context of A, intent A will only get triggered when the contexts of B, C and D are active all the same time.

Should Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Documentation[1], there is no way to match an intent if there is one context inactive.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-input-output#input_contexts